# Finding freetype2 library from versions 2.4.8 and 2.5.2

Tags: cmake, freetype

I have a program that relies on the freetype6-dev package. When installing this package, you get different versions when doing it on Ubuntu 14.04 vs 12.02. When doing `freetype-config --ftversion`, you get 2.5.2 and 2.4.8 respectively. The problem I have is when I am trying to find these libraries using cmake. With 2.4.8, it finds ft2build.h then goes into `<freetype/config/ftheader.h>` to find the rest of the header. In 2.5.2, it goes into `<config/ftheader.h>`. I am not using the built in FindFreeType in cmake since there are some builds which already have ft2build.h included and I want it to use the one in that directory instead of the system. Here is what my custom FindFreeTypeTwo.cmake looks like.

```
  1 # - Try to find Freetype2                                                                                               
  2 # Once done this will define                                                                                            
  3 #                                                                                                                       
  4 #  FREETYPE2_FOUND       - system has FREETYPE2                                                                         
  5 #  FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR - the Freetype2 include directory                                                              
  6 #  FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES   - Link these to use Freetype2                                                                  
  7                                                                                                                         
  8 #handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set FREETYPE2_FOUND to TRUE if                                           
  9 #all listed variables are TRUE                                                                                          
 10 FIND_PATH(_FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR ft2build.h PATH_SUFFIXES freetype2)                                                    
 11                                                                                                                         
 12 FIND_LIBRARY(_FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES NAMES freetype)                                                                       
 13                                                                                                                         
 14 INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)                                                                                  
 15 FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(Freetype2 DEFAULT_MSG _FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES _FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR)                    
 16                                                                                                                         
 17 MARK_AS_ADVANCED(FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES)                                                             
 18                                                                                                                         
 19 # Set up output variables                                                                                               
 20 if (FREETYPE2_FOUND)                                                                                                    
 21   set (FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR ${_FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR})                                                                 
 22   set (FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES ${_FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES})                                                                     
 23 else(FREETYPE2_FOUND)                                                                                                   
 24   set (FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR)                                                                                           
 25   set (FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES)                                                                                             
 26 endif (FREETYPE2_FOUND)
```

So that works if `freetype-config --ftversion` is 2.5.2 and not for 2.4.8. If I change it to

```
FIND_PATH(_FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR ft2build.h)
...
if(FREETYPE2_FOUND)
   set (FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR ${_FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR}/freetype2)
   set (FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES ${_FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES})
else
...
```

My program can find the headers for freetype in 2.4.8, but 2.5.2 fails.

How can I modify cmake so that it will work regardless of the freetype version?

Comment: Searching include directirues for 2.5.2, then for 2.4.8 doesn't help? `FIND_PATH` can be issued many times.

Comment: The `FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR` would depend on which directory freetype was found in. Wouldn't that cause issues?

Comment: Would the built-in `FindFreetype.cmake` work for you if it found your installation instead of the system one? If so, you could try to (1) give hints to `FindFreetype.cmake`'s `find_path` by setting path variables, e.g. `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH`, `FREETYPE_DIR`. (2) Copy the entire built-in `FindFreetype.cmake` and modify where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute `freetype-config --ftversion` during configuration, parse its output and choose `FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR` accordingly:

```
if(_FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR)
    execute_process (COMMAND "freetype-config" "--ftversion"
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE version_output)
    string (REGEX MATCH "([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)"
        FREETYPE2_VERSION "${version_output}")
    set(FREETYPE2_VERSION_MAJOR ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
    set(FREETYPE2_VERSION_MINOR ${CMAKE_MATCH_2})
    set(FREETYPE2_VERSION_TWEAK ${CMAKE_MATCH_3})

    if(FREETYPE2_VERSION_MINOR EQUAL "4")
        set (FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR ${_FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR}/freetype2)
    else()
        set (FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR ${_FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR})
    endif()
endif()
```

By iniializing versions-related variables you also allow `version` request in `find_package()` call.